# Unable to start activity after click on android notification

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-studio, notifications

I know, I am asking repeated question but I have tried everything and read every Q/A on SO. Still unable to start new activity when click on notification. I am using NotificationCompat.

Below is my main activity

```
package notification.test.example.com.notificationtest;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private static final String NOTIFICATION_CONTENT_TITLE = "Notification Test";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button button  = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn1);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                loadNotification();
            }
        });
    }

    private void loadNotification() {

        int requestId = (int)System.currentTimeMillis();
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), NotificationDetailsActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        intent.putExtra("msg", "Notification Details activity launched");

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), requestId, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT | PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getApplication().getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext()).
                setSmallIcon(R.drawable. abc_btn_check_material).setContentTitle(NOTIFICATION_CONTENT_TITLE)
                .setSound(Settings.System.DEFAULT_NOTIFICATION_URI)
                .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText("Welcome"))
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setContentText("This is Notification test")
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .setSubText("-------------------This is notification sub text area-------------------")
                .setTicker("Notify Title");

        notificationManager.notify(1, builder.build());
    }
}
```

Below is my DetailNotification java file.

```
package notification.test.example.com.notificationtest;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.PersistableBundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

/**
 * Created by sony on 06-06-2015.
 */
public class NotificationDetailsActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState, PersistableBundle persistentState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState, persistentState);

        setContentView(R.layout.notification_layout);
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String data = intent.getStringExtra("msg");
        Log.d(NotificationDetailsActivity.class.getName(),data+"--------------------------------------------------------------");
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Message : "+data, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="notification.test.example.com.notificationtest" >

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".NotificationDetailsActivity"
            android:label="Notification Detail Activity"></activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

build.gradle file.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "notification.test.example.com.notificationtest"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'
}
```

Expert please guide me where I am wrong, I have already spent 5-6 hr.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be try this istead of below line:

```
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), requestId, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT | PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
```

Use this line:

```
 PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 1, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

> Edited

And what more you can do is just remove second parameter from NotificationDetailActivity class and from super.onCreate() calling methos also

Comment: What's the difference b/w these above two lines??? And I have tried also your suggestion, still problem exist.

Comment: Your Notification Activity require call api 21. Are you developing for lollipop??

Comment: My targetsdk version is 21 and I am testing it on lollypop also. Is this the problem?

Comment: Just remove second parameter from Notification class Nd from super.onCreate also from both lines and try

Comment: you are talking about NotificationDetailActivity?

Comment: Yes!! i have checked your code and its wokring in my device which is kitkat

Comment: Thanks alot. Could you please tell me the problem? I didn't get this

Answer (score 0):

Try adding another activity... Maybe Ur code should work on this way

Comment: Another activity means?

Comment: It was already there in manifest file, now i have updated my question also.

Comment: Maybe ur right... Ur target sdk is too high maybe u should lower it

Comment: I have tried v7 support jar, may be problem should not with the version.

Comment: Maybe u should support It On ur targeted sdk.. also yeah maybe It wont work cause the version is not Compatible with the version or it is not Compatible on ur cp

Answer (score 0):

I have used **Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK** on my [example](http://www.panayiotisgeorgiou.net/start-activity-once-notification-clicked/) and worked for me perfectly.

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(context, DoSomething.class);
 PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
        context, 
        0, 
        myIntent, 
        Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
```